# using <DrizzleContext.Consumer> re-renders the component infinitely

Tags: drizzle

I'm trying to build a simple dapp using drizzle-react's 'DrizzleContext'. This is how my index.js file looks like:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Drizzle, generateStore } from "drizzle";
import { DrizzleContext } from "drizzle-react";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
//import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import drizzleOptions from './drizzleOptions';

const drizzleStore = generateStore(drizzleOptions);
const drizzle = new Drizzle(drizzleOptions, drizzleStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    (<DrizzleContext.Provider drizzle={drizzle} >
        <App />
    </DrizzleContext.Provider>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Also, this is how my  component looks like:

```js
import React from "react";
import { DrizzleContext } from "drizzle-react";

    export default () => (
        <DrizzleContext.Consumer>
            {drizzleContext => {
                const { drizzle, drizzleState, initialized } = drizzleContext;

                if (!initialized) {
                    return "Loading...";
                }

                console.log("value of initialized: ");
                console.log(initialized);

                return (
                    <div>hello world</div>
                );
            }}
        </DrizzleContext.Consumer>
    )
```

turns out that using < DrizzleContext.Consumer > tag starts re-rendering the complete state infinitely, as is evident in the console log where all the mentioned logs keep repeating. Is this normal behavior ? Is there a way we can arrest this infinite re-render inside a **Functional Component** ?